# fragment shows only one list

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to show two lists from my fragment. When I show the first one (array1), it's ok. But when I add the second one it just replaces the first and I see only the second list (array 2). Here is my code, could please tell me what's the problem here?

Here is my fragment file:

```
public class ToFragment extends ListFragment {   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] array1 = {
                "listitem1",
                "listitem2"
        };
        String[] array2 = {
                "listitem1"
        };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(), R.layout.trainlist, R.id.traintextviewid);
        adapter1.addAll(array1);    
        setListAdapter(adapter1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(), R.layout.trainlist, R.id.timetextviewid);
        adapter2.addAll(array2);    
        setListAdapter(adapter2);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Here is tofragment.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/trainlist"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/timelist"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>         
</LinearLayout>
```

And trainlist.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/traintextviewid"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timetextviewid"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want it to look like two lists, second is low-width. Please tell me what to do!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the topic but in your code you're using ``R.layout.trainlist`` id for both adapters. Could it be the reason?

Comment: I was told that it doesn't matter in case I don't use this layout. I've tried to use it with other layout but it didn't work

Comment: Ah I didn't notice you were using ListFragment. I do not know it too well either but based on the documentation it seems one ListFragment can show one list only. Adding two separate such fragments could fix the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to merge two arrays and show result in listview, add them to one ArrayAdapter. Do not create adapter for every array.

```
    adapter1.addAll(array1); 
    adapter1.addAll(array2);       
    setListAdapter(adapter1);
```

if you want separate lists you should use custom fragment with two listliews or two ListFragments (one listfragment for one list).

Answer (score 0):

`ListFragment` cannot support more than one list. If you need more, use regular `Fragment` as host.

Answer (score 0):

1. `ListView` in `ListFragment` is held under `android.R.id.list`. There can be only one. Use a `Fragment` with that view.
2. If you are trying to fit the `ListFragment` where `android:id="@+id/fragment_container"` resides, you are already doing it wrong. You are trying to put a `Fragment` into `Fragment` so you can `Fragment`.
3. Stop using hardcoded `android:layout_width`